# Multi Flagging the same post

Tags: support, review, flags, spam, low-quality-posts

I am not sure if this is by design or if it is a bug but it appears that one user can multi flag the same post.  The answer below:

[Are there tours available from Seoul to the Korean Demilitarized Zone?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14632/are-there-tours-available-from-seoul-to-the-korean-demilitarized-zone/23312#23312)

I had flagged as Spam but it also appeared in the Review under Low Quality posts, which I had marked again as not an answer, which created another moderator flag and created an unintended comment for the post.

Is this a bug or is this a feature we should be mindful of?

**Additional info based on the answer**

I've just multi flagged the following answer:

[Can I live in Munich - Germany for a month with 500 Eur](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13139/can-i-live-in-munich-germany-for-a-month-with-500-eur/23348#23348)

as NAA twice.  Once from Review of Low Quality Posts and 2nd from the flag link under the answer.

Picture below shows flags recorded for both questions.  Only 1 gets recorded but 2 actions were taken.

[image]

Comment: This post is going to get so many test flags.

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of the multiple flags in your flag history (NAA's)?

Comment: No.  Shows only 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot flag a post *for the same reason* (excluding "other"; you can flag a post using a custom reason as many times as you want) more than once.  You can flag a post for multiple different reasons simultaneously.

Flagging a post as spam means you can't flag it as spam again, not that you can't flag it as NAA.

Comment: Not really.  If I flag directly from the answer as spam.  I can't add another flag.  Nor I can add a different flag reviewing in multiple queues (I think, haven't tried it in awhile) but I can add one in Review and another directly, and spam is not one of flags avaiable in Review.

Comment: @Karlson I just went through my flag history and this is what I observed.  Are you perhaps looking at already deleted answers?  Once it is deleted the only flag option is "other".  And of course, flagging as spam can auto-delete, so it's possible that you cast the final vote, deleting the post immediately.

Comment: At the time the answer wasn't deleted.  And it wasn't me. :)

Comment: @Karlson Are you sure?  It could have been deleted without appearing deleted, if you hadn't yet refreshed the page.  The flag dialog is built dynamically, based on the current state of the post, not the state of the post when the page was first loaded.  If it was deleted after the page was loaded, it would explain the behavior.

Comment: I am sure.  I marked as Spam.  Then went to review(in the same tab) and marked as NAA, which posts a helpful comment automatically.  This is marked as 1 hour ago.  The post was deleted 17 minutes ago.  I don't want to create a test answer but I can just to verify my claim.

Comment: Can confirm that he mentioned this in the travel chat BEFORE my vote to delete the answer, which was then deleted a couple of minutes later by a mod as well.

Comment: Sorry @Servy Unfortunately you can flag it twice as NAA.  See amended question